# Scrollview width constant in ipad pro

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, scrollview

I have added few items in a scroll view for my ipad app. But when i render the screen on ipad pro the width of the scroll view is not getting increased according to the ipad pro width.

This is the scroll view constraints.

[image]

What do i need to do extra to make it adjust the width accordingly.

Comment: Give equal width constraint to scrollview w.r.t. the VC view.

Comment: it is because you need to give width to subview of scrollview . because size of scrollview calculate as per its subview's size